# Export function/class from node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, export, mocha.js

I have a class that I've defined in Javascript like this:

```
var CoolClass = function() {
  this.prop1 = 'cool';
  this.prop2 = 'neato';
}

CoolClass.prototype.doCoolThings = function(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(arg1 + ' is pretty ' + this.prop1;
}

modules.export = CoolClass;
```

I need to be able to export this so I can test it in Mocha by using require. But I'd also like to still allow this class to be instantiated in the browser.

As of now, I can load this into a browser, instantiate it and it's good to go. (Obviously I get an error in the console about not understanding the keyword 'export' or 'module')

Typically I export multiple single functions using

```
exports.someFunction = function(args){};
```

But now that I want to just export that one function, none of the methods that I've added via the prototype chain are defined.

I've tried module.exports but that doesn't seem to do the trick either. My Mocha spec requires the file like this:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var coolClass = require('../cool-class.js');
var myCoolClass;

beforeEach(function() {
  myCoolClass = new coolClass();// looks like here is where the issue is
});

describe('CoolClass', function() {
  // if I instantiate the class here, it works.
  // the methods that were added to CoolClass are all undefined

});
```

It looks like my beforeEach in Mocha is where it gets tripped up. I can instantiate the class in the actual spec, and it works just fine.

Comment: Could you try my answer below? I think you need to put that beforeEach in a parent describe. Details on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mochajs, you need to put your `beforeEach` inside a parent `describe`, and have your specific scenarios on children `describe`s. Else, things done in `beforeEach` doesn't get recognized by your `describe`. Your myCoolClass is just treated as a global variable and nothing was really instantiated, that's why the prototype functions are undefined.

So it's somewhat like (sorry I'm just on mobile):

```
var MyCoolClass = require('mycoolclass.js');
describe('MyModule', function () {
  var myCoolClass;

  beforeEach(function () {
    myCoolClass = new MyCoolClass();
  });

  describe('My Scenario 1', function () {
    myCoolClass.doSomethingCool('This'); //or do an assert
   });
});
```

You can look at its [documentation](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#asynchronous-code) for further details.

Comment: Complete flub on my part. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I spoke too soon. The beforeEach flat out doesn't work no matter where I put it. But to be honest, the issue is now outside the scope of the original question. I'll google around a bit, and if I can't fix it, I'll post a completely different question.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Sure, I'm also interested with what issue you are facing.